# How to mask EditText to take input in specific format

Tags: android, android-edittext, masking

I'm trying to restrict what my EditText takes as input. I want it to take a maximum of `21 million (20,999,999.99999999)`. Is it possible to achieve> if, then how do I go about it? I've tried using `InputFilter` with a pattern `[0-9]{0,9}+((\.[0-9]{0,7})?)||(\.)?`. Show me how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I read Francesco's answer and your comment also. If you need to check the decimal point, you can try this below.

```
EditText someText = findViewById(R.id.someValueInputHi);
String paw = someText.getText().toString().replaceAll("\\s+", ""); //rem unusual spaces
Double someInput = Double.parseDouble(paw);
if (someInput < 5.3465726543d | someInput > 3.7834657836d) {
    //Ok now
} else {
    //Oops, no man
}
```

You only take the value between **5.3465726543** and **3.7834657836**.

**Why double?**

As the name implies, a double has 2x the precision of float. In general, a *double has **15** decimal digits of precision*, while float has 7.

**EDIT:**
Francesco's answer is now deleted.